# Including zeroes in average count calculation

Tags: r

I have a dataset of obvservations of several different species. There is a list of survey sites and what species each individual observed there was:

```
Survey    Species
  1          A
  1          C
  2          B
  3          D
  4          NA
```

So each line is a sighting, with the info of what species that was. I am trying to calculate average number observed for each species, including the zeroes for surveys on which it was not observed (and surveys for which no individuals were observed: Species = NA).

My first thought was to use plyr:

```
avg_count = ddply(df, c("Survey", "Species"), summarise, count =
                  length(Species)/length(unique(df$Survey)))
```

but I'm pretty sure that is not including the surveys where none of a particular species is seen.

Ideal output would be something along the lines of the following:

```
Species      Average Count
   A              0.03
   B              0.5
   C              0.013
   D              0.29
   E              0.08
```

Comment: Can you show how your desired output should look like?

Comment: Try `table(DF)` and then `?prop.table` if you want proportions.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Ideally, I'd like a list of all species observed on at least one survey and the associate average count, I'll edit the post

Comment: Your desired output should match the provided data. Maybe edit the data accordingly.

Comment: @Frank That got me exactly what I wanted! Thank you.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it! I'm not exactly clear on your goal, but you could post your own answer below, illustrating what worked for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Frank for giving me the core of this answer. Here is what I did:

```
df = table(df)
df = prop.table(df)
df = as.data.frame(df)
df$Count = df$Freq*5005 ##this was the total number of individual observations I had
```

That got me the count of every species on every survey. I then combined it with ddply to get the means, etc.:

```
summary = ddply(df, "Species", summarise, average = mean(Count))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for because I am not sure if your desired output is associated with the example data you provided. But similar to your solution but possibly more efficient is the following:

```
### it is usually helpful for people 
### to help if you have code to 
### specifically reproduce the data
data <- data.frame(c(1,1,2,3,4),c("A","C","B","D",NA))
colnames(data) <- c("Survey","Species")


### i use the suggested prop.table() and table()
df <- prop.table(table(data))
### here, however, I decide to use data.table() rather than data.frame()
### because of its super helpful properties
df <- data.table(df)

df <- df[,list("Freq"=sum(N)),by=Species]

> df
   Species Freq
1:       A  0.25
2:       B  0.25
3:       C  0.25
4:       D  0.25
```

You can then multiply the `df$Freq`values by your total count.